# cordova javascript shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap

I am developing a cordova app. In this app i am call a website. web page is coming correctly the page have an a button. I want to show an a alert when the button click. The web page  button code is shown below. In web there is no button click is defined.

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Take Picture &raquo;</a></p>
```

The cordova code is

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);        
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    // Here, we redirect to the web site.
    var targetUrl = "http://mysite/mypage.php/";
    var bkpLink = document.getElementById("bkpLink");
    bkpLink.setAttribute("href", targetUrl);
    bkpLink.text = targetUrl;
    window.location.replace(targetUrl);
    //I want to call a alert when button click      
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-lg')[0].addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
    return function() {
        alert("okkkkkkkkkk");
    };
    })(i), false);  

    },
    // Note: This code is taken from the Cordova CLI template.
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
    }

};
app.initialize();
```

When running this code it shows the 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js`

I don't how to solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Where have you included this script ,`<script src="cordova.js"></script>` . Is it before your `js` file ?

Comment: cordova.js file is not seen in my project. when i create a new project in cordova the cordova.js is not seeing.

Comment: No. You must add this script. The file will be generated when a build is taken. Then take a build. It should work.

Comment: It is already added in index.html